# MS Robotics Studio: "contract is different from that of the namespace"

Tags: namespaces, contract, robotics-studio

I'm trying to build a DSS service using MS Robotics Studio and VS 2008, but when I build, I get an error from dssproxy.exe saying:

```
    The class MyServiceName has a ContractAttribute but the contract is different from that of the namespace.
```

and the build fails because dssproxy returns code 10.  Does anyone know what this message means?

The Contract identifier is declared in the Types class file and used in the attribute declaration just the way the Add New Project > Dss Service wizard builds them.  My understanding is that the identifier is just a unique string.  Is this trying to tell me it must match my namespace somehow?

If I build again, the error goes away, but if I force a rebuild or clean before building, it comes back.

Thanks,
  Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself:  If the contract identifier contains capital letters, this error will occur, even in it matches the manifest exactly.  Both the identifier in the types and the manifest must be all lowercase.  Unfortunately, the Add New Project dialog doesn't prevent you from entering mixed-case for this. :(